# HTMLPurifier Adding <p> around images

Tags: htmlpurifier

Hello for some reason HTMLPurifier (v4.10) is adding a Paragraph Tag around img tags and  removing the style attribute on them.

This is my config.

```
    $config->set("AutoFormat.AutoParagraph", false);
    $config->set("AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.Predicate", ['colgroup' => [], 'th' => [], 'td' => [], 'iframe' => ['src'], 'div' => ['class']]);
    $config->set("AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty", true);
    $config->set("Core.NormalizeNewlines", true);
    $config->set('HTML.Allowed', "*[style|class],h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, pre, code, blockquote, table, tr, td, th, thead, tbody, strong, em, b, i, u, s, span, a, p, br, ul, ol, li, img[src], div");
```

This is a example of what i'm purifying.

```
<div class="some_class">
<img src='http://example.com/test.jpg' style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%'>
</div>
```

What it ends up spiting out is:

```
<div class="some_class">
<p><img src='http://example.com/test.jpg' alt='test' /></p>
</div>
```

Also setting Core.RemoveInvalidImg true/false does nothing. Same thing happens.

**Edit:**

```
Here is full code sample:
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$my_text = file_get_contents('test3.md');
preg_match_all('/[<]style[^>]*[>]([^<]+)[<]\/style[>]/', $my_text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style type="text/css">';

for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    echo $matches[1][$i][0]."\n\n";
}

echo '</style></head><body>';


$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set("AutoFormat.AutoParagraph", false);
$config->set("AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.Predicate", ['colgroup' => [], 'th' => [], 'td' => [], 'iframe' => ['src'], 'div' => ['class']]);
$config->set("AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty", true);
$config->set("Core.NormalizeNewlines", true);
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', "*[style|class],h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, pre, code, blockquote, table, tr, td, th, thead, tbody, strong, em, b, i, u, s, span, a, p, br, ul, ol, li, img[src], div");

$config->set('HTML.Allowed', "*[style|class],h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, pre, code, blockquote, table, tr, td, th, thead, tbody, strong, em, b, i, u, s, span, a, p, br, ul, ol, li, img[src], div");
$Purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

echo $Purifier->purify($page);

?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I only noticed you edited your question now! Getting back to this: Unfortunately, the edited code doesn't work, since `$page` is not set. :( If I replace it with `$my_text`, it _still_ doesn't add `<p>` around `<img>`, though. Since I'm unable to reproduce your problem even with your code, I'm at a loss. I recommend going through your `php.ini` and playing around with the settings, see if anything in there is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This file:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

$config->set("AutoFormat.AutoParagraph", false);
$config->set("AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.Predicate", ['colgroup' => [], 'th' => [], 'td' => [], 'iframe' => ['src'], 'div' => ['class']]);
$config->set("AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty", true);
$config->set("Core.NormalizeNewlines", true);
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', "*[style|class],h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, pre, code, blockquote, table, tr, td, th, thead, tbody, strong, em, b, i, u, s, span, a, p, br, ul, ol, li, img[src], div");

$dirty_html = "<div class=\"some_class\">
<img src='http://example.com/test.jpg' style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%'>
</div>";

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
echo $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

...gives me the following output:

```
<div class="some_class">
<img src="http://example.com/test.jpg" alt="test.jpg" /></div>
```

Can you tell us a bit more about your setup? To me it looks like something else is going on here, such as something intercepting your purifying call and doing a completely different handling (e.g. applying an auto-paragraph logic) - notice for example how one might expect HTML Purifier to turn your single-quoted attribute values to double-quoted attribute values, which it isn't doing according to your question.

See whether you can rule out any third-party involvement?

Comment: Using file_get_contents i'm pulling markdown file. Form there i'm extracting any and all <style> tags using preg_match_all. Then running it through htmlpurifier and echoing the output there is the <p> wrapping it. I don't even get to next steps.

Comment: Can you show your code? (Also, what happens if you try to run my script in your environment? Long shot, but do you have magic quotes on?) @Pyromanci